# Mapping a Key on the Keyboard to Exit Loop in Arduino

Tags: arduino

I want to create a function on the Arduino and put it in all the loops in my program such that whenever during use, the user can press the "Esc" key on the keyboard to cancel what it is currently doing. A serial monitor is being used with my current code.

My entire code is very long which is why I don't have it posted, but if you can answer the situation i described above, I will be able to implement it. You can imagine a simple loop running forever that will exit anytime the "Esc" key is pressed.

Comment: This needs context, i.e. code, to make sense. If I had a serial monitor with an open connection to an arduino running right now and I pressed ESC while writing this comment *in the browser*, should something magically happen on the arduino in the background?! You must have some non-arduino code running to catch the ESC - we need to see that.

Comment: I don't expect this to be done when you are outside the serial monitor. Can this be done when the user is on the serial monitor? I would prefer no outside programs being run in conjunction with the Arduino.

Comment: Which serial monitor? Which OS? Chances are you'll simply close the window, the arduino will reset and that's it. You need to code something; not use a ready-made serial monitor

Comment: if you have long code, you dont have to paste everything, just give us some relevant code so that we can see it.